# What is the difference between <T> and <T extends Object> in java?

Tags: java, generics, casting

In Java generics, What is the advantage of using `class GenericStack<T extends Object> {}` over `class GenericStack<T>{}`.

I have implemented a generic stack using both of the above approaches but unable to trace out the difference. Help me to understand this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no difference. `<T>` and `<T extends Object>` are equivalent.