# What is the point of stating that a type wildcard must extend Object?

Tags: java, generics

Oracle provides some java [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/QandE/generics-questions.html) questions with [answers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/QandE/generics-answers.html). This is problem 8.

> Write a generic method to find the maximal element in the range
>   [begin, end) of a list.

solution

```
import java.util.*;

public final class Algorithm {
    public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>>
        T max(List<? extends T> list, int begin, int end) {

        T maxElem = list.get(begin);

        for (++begin; begin < end; ++begin)
            if (maxElem.compareTo(list.get(begin)) < 0)
                maxElem = list.get(begin);
        return maxElem;
    }
}
```

In the method signature

```
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(List<? extends T> list, int begin, int end)
```

What is the point of stating that T must extend Object? Doesn't everything do that anyway? Is this redundant?

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795995/java-generics-special-usage-t-extends-object-interface

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30206340/what-is-the-difference-between-t-and-t-extends-object-in-java

Comment: From the accepted answer on 8055389 they link the oracle docs, which use something very close to your specific example. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/convert.html